# What is the play asset delivery "install time" asset saved directory

Tags: android, html, android-assets

in app's html I try to access the asset from the play assets delivery install-time failed. So What is the play asset delivery "install time" asset saved directory after the app installed? I am stucking here for couple days, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
var layer_AI_0 = L.tileLayer(function(z, x, y) {
var path = "Tiles_001/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg";
var assetManager = getAssets();
var fd = assetManager.openFd(path);
var url = URL.createObjectURLSync(fd);
 return new L.ImageTileLayer(url);
}, {
pane: 'pane_AI_0',
opacity: 1.0,
attribution: '',
minZoom: 9,
maxZoom: 14,
minNativeZoom: 9,
maxNativeZoom: 14
});
```

Comment: Code please....